# "Better not X" or "better not to X?"

Tags: grammar, participles

What's the correct construction?

Example sentence:

> A bear! Better not (to) move or it would devour her.

Should the *to* be there? Why or why not?

Comment: WHY? - because the speaker assumes his "sentence" as given is short for something like ***It would be** better not to [do something]*. WHY NOT? - because he thinks it's short for something like ***I/We had** better not [do something]*. In short, both versions are fine, and it's a matter of personal choice which to use.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Won't you turn that into an answer?

Comment: @Ronald Sole: I'm still trying to figure out exactly why it would be feasible for me to respond to your comment with ***Better not!*** if I disagreed, whereas if I *did* agree it would be a complete no-no to respond with ***Better!***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "better not move" sentence seems like an imperative (you are commanding the other party---after all, there's a bear).  Placing the "to" after the not sounds a bit awkward to my ear but it is less imperative, like a suggestion. Perhaps "It would be better not to move..." would be a way to rephrase the sentence if the bear were far away.